# How can we know what precision the I/O of GLSL functions use?

Tags: glsl, opengl-es-2.0

[Apple says](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html)

> Many built-in functions use
>   medium-precision inputs and outputs.
>   If your application provides
>   low-precision floating-point values as
>   parameters or assigns the results to a
>   low-precision floating-point variable,
>   the shader may have to include
>   additional instructions to convert the
>   values.

Where is this information located?  I didn't find it [in the spec.](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf)  (I've been using *lowp* all over the place, and have concerns about it after checking out the link at the top.)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used iPhone's implementation yet (just on WebGL and Android) but as i can see from the Apple snippet you posted, they are stating that **their** implementation uses `mediump`, so if you're using `lowp` then **their** implementation will have to convert those low precision floating point values to medium precision values (floating point conversion isn't like integer conversions, they have to adjust mantissas and exponents).

Remember that GLSL (or HLSL for DX11) shaders get compiled into implementation specific code.